# How to use selenium webdriver methods inside robotframework library?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I want to use selenium webdriver methods in the robot framework library.

```
def custom_go_to
        driver = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
        driver.go_to(url)
```

The above code from custom library works fine, but I want to use selenium method at the place of robotframework builtin library.
When I try to use **driver.get(url)** it says

```
'SeleniumLibrary' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The custom library I created ERP.py looks like

```
class ERP: 
   @keyword
    def custom_go_to(self, url):
        driver = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
        driver.get(url)
```

And Test Case looks like

```
***Settings***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library  path_to_lib/ERP.py

*** Variable ***
${BROWSER}  |  chrome
${URL}  |  facebook.com

***Test Cases***
Open the browser using an inbuilt keyword and go to a given URL using custom go to using EventFiringWebDriver.
     Open Browser |  about:blank  |  ${BROWSER}
     Custom Go To  |   ${URL}
```

How can I use Selenium webdriver methods inside the robot framework library?

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to achieve here, but the newest `SeleniumLibrary` does not have `Get` keyword... Please try again with an existing keyword.

Comment: I want to use all Selenium keywords inside the robotframework library. Like we do normally when we use Selenium with Python only.

Comment: Still, there is no `Get` keyword in `SeleniumLibrary`...

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out,  I just updated the question. I want to use webdriver methods. :)

Comment: There's a quite good tutorial for Python and webdriver here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selenium library itself is not a webdriver object, it's just an instance of the SeleniumLibrary class. You need to get a reference to the driver, which is an attribute in the library.

```
def custom_go_to(url):
    selib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
    selib.driver.get(url)
```

For more information about interacting with SeleniumLibrary at a low level, see the document [Extending SeleniumLibrary](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/docs/extending/extending.rst) in the SeleniumLibrary git repository.

Comment: Thank you Bryan, this is exactly what I wanted to know. I've achieved the same by creating the plugin with the help of LibraryComponent. In plugin I'm using it as `self.driver.get(url)` and it works but **self** doesn't work with the library, why?

Comment: @DivakshJain: I don't know what you mean by "self doesn't work with the library". `self` works the same way in all python code. There's nothing unique about robot keyword classes or selenium that would make it work differently.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you once again. :)

Answer (score 0):

'SeleniumLibrary' do not have get attribute. Please refer to [Selenium Library Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/) for more info.

You should be using

```
Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}
```

Below is example from the link 
Example

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Simple example using SeleniumLibrary.
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${LOGIN URL}      http://localhost:7272
${BROWSER}        Chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    Open Browser To Login Page


*** Keywords ***
Open Browser To Login Page
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked. There are good reasons for using a custom keyword rather that using the pre-built keywords.

Answer (score 0):

SeleniumLibrary have a "Get Element Attribute" keyword.

See documentation here:
[RobotFramework SeleniumLibrary Documentation](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute)

Answer (score -1):

Reproduced this as well:

`driver.get(url)` produces `AttributeError: 'SeleniumLibrary' object has no attribute 'get'`

An error with an existing keyword, such as `driver.go_to(url)` produces a different error: `No browser is open.`

So, use existing keywords or make your own.

Comment: _"So, use existing keywords or make your own."_ - that's exactly what they are trying to do: make their own.

Comment: yes, _exactly_ in the case of `driver.get()`. They are wanting to create a custom keyword that calls `driver.get()`.

Comment: In this case, `driver.get()` does not exist, so, it must be created or then change to another keyword than `get()`, thus, "So, use existing keywords or make your own". You can create a million custom keywords, but that doesn't make that `driver.get()` working.

Comment: You are misreading the question. the `get` method is a standard method of a browser driver. That is what they want to call.  In the question they are incorrectly assuming that the instance of SeleniumLibrary is a _driver_. It is not.

Comment: They changed some of the wording, but even the original version of the question said they wanted to call the low level `get` method of the selenium driver. That method exists, but it exists on the _driver_, not on the instance of SeleniumLibrary.

Comment: "I want to use selenium keywords in the robot framework library." -> Get is not a Selenium keyword.

And "How can I use Selenium functions inside the robot framework library?"

Nothing specific about webdriver in the original post. Just how to use SeleniumLibrary.

Comment: _"How can I use Selenium functions..."_ is asking how to use _selenium_ functions, not functions in SeleniumLibrary. There is the high level keyword library SeleniumLibrary, and the low level api for interacting with selenium. They are asking about the latter. Admittedly the first version of the question is poorly written, but it seems clear to me even in that first draft that they want to call the low level functions rather than the SeleniumLibrary keywords.